# Haskell - How to traverse through a list and reverse elements

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble locating documentation on simple operations in Haskell.

I have a list of lists (`:: [[a]]`) and I need to reverse all of the element lists `x` where `length x >= 2`.

So far I haven't found anything on:

- How to traverse the lists
- How would I find the length of the element. There is the `length` function I can use, but I haven't got an idea how to use it.

I did find the `reverse` function for lists, though I had trouble finding it.

If any help on those individual implementation, it would be greatly appreciated. I can piece them together.

Comment: You should consider searching in [**`Hoogle`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to traverse the lists.

There are several sequence functions, from the more basic `fmap`, which maps a single function over a list, to `foldr`, which folds a list structure around a binary operation (for summing a list or similar operations) to the `sequence`/`traverse` operations, which carry monadic or applicative effects.

> How would I find the length of the element. There is the length function I can use, but I haven't got an idea how to use it.

There is a `length` function; you use it like any other function. `length xs`, where `xs` is a list. If you still aren't certain how to do that, I would suggest starting slower with a Haskell tutorial.

> And I have this to reverse the list, But i think i have that now.

There is a `reverse` function. If you don't want to use the built-in one (or if you want to do it yourself for educational purposes), you could build an efficient reverse function with an accumulator.

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' xs = doReverse xs []
    where doReverse [] ys = ys
          doReverse (x:xs) ys = doReverse xs (x:ys)
```

Comment: @ReidBarton `fmap` is a generalization of `map`. `map` only works on lists, `fmap` works on every `Functor` including lists.

Comment: @recursion.ninja FYI, Reid Barton is a major GHC compiler developer among other things. He's trying to make a point here, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Perhaps my wording wasn't the most precise, but I usually do use `fmap`, even for lists. The only reason I've ever heard used to justify the existence of a separate `map` function is "it's easier for novices to understand".

Comment: @SilvioMayolo "it's easier for novices to understand"... and here we are on SO answering questions from novices. ;)

Answer (score 7):

> I need to reverse all of the element lists x where `length x >= 2`

You can totally ignore the `length x >= 2` part, since if the length of a list is 0 or 1, reversing it has no effect: there's no way to tell whether you reversed it or not, so you might as well just reverse all lists, for uniformity.

Given that, this is super simple: you just need to `map reverse` over the list of lists, reversing each one in turn:

```
reverseEach :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reverseEach = map reverse

> reverseEach [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8]]
[[3,2,1],[4],[8,7,6,5]]
```

And as other answers suggest, you can afford to generalize a little bit:

```
reverseEach :: Functor f => f [a] -> f [a]
reverseEach = fmap reverse

> reverseEach [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8]]
[[3,2,1],[4],[8,7,6,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
conditionallyReverse :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
ConditionallyReverse listOfLists= fmap f listOfLists
  where 
    f list
      | length list >= 2 = reverse x
      | otherwise        = x
```

We apply the function `f` to each element of the `listOfLists` by supplying `f` as the first argument to `fmap` and the `listOfLists` as the second argument. The function `f` transforms a `list` based on the condition `length list >= 2`. If the condition holds, the list is reversed, *otherwise* the original list is returned.

Comment: Thank you, But you didn't have to provide the answer. I know the logic but haven't got a clue on how to implement the code! Helps a lot!

Comment: @NeedHelp, note that if `xs` is a list, you really should never ask `length xs > n`, because this has to walk the whole (possibly long) list just to see that it's not too short. The simplest way to check (for `n>=1`) is probably `not . null . drop (n - 1) $ xs`. As amalloy points out, the check isn't even necessary in this partcular case.

Comment: @dfeuer If you're feeling cheeky, `genericLength xs >= (2 ::`[`Natural`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-Natural.html)`)` is as efficient as you could hope for, and very nearly as readable as the original `length xs >= 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Absurd over-generalization:

Every `Traversable` instance supports a horrible hack implementing `reverse`. There may be a cleaner or more efficient way to do this; I'm not sure.

```
module Rev where
import Data.Traversable
import Data.Foldable
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
import Prelude hiding (foldl)

fill :: Traversable t => t b -> [a] -> t a
fill = evalState . traverse go
  where
    go _ = do
      xs <- get
      put (drop 1 xs)
      return (head xs)

reverseT :: Traversable t => t a -> t a
reverseT xs = fill xs $ foldl (flip (:)) [] xs

reverseAll :: (Functor f, Traversable t) => f (t a) -> f (t a)
reverseAll = fmap reverseT
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of folds:

```
reverse  =  foldl (\ acc x -> x : acc) []
length  =  foldl' (\ n _ -> n + 1) 0
map f  =  foldr (\ x xs -> f x : xs)
```

letting

```
mapReverse  =  map (\ xs -> if length xs >= 2 then reverse xs else xs)
```

But `length` is a costly O(n), and `reverse [x]  =  [x]`. I would use

```
map reverse [[1,2,3],[4],[]]  ==  [[3,2,1],[4],[]]
```

where `(map reverse)  ::  [[a]] -> [[a]]`. `map reverse` isn't basic enough to justify an own name binding.